# Repository creation fails while upgrading OWB11gR1(11.1.0.7) to OWB11gR2(11.2.0.4)

Tags: oracle, etl, data-warehouse

I need to a new workspace in OWB11gR2(11.2.0.4) to upgrade OWB11gR1(11.1.0.7). Repository Assistant fails after processing 64%. The following is the error log.

```
main.TaskScheduler timer[5]20200714@08:45:58.058: 00> oracle.wh.service.impl.assistant.ProcessEngine.display(ProcessEngine.java:2122): % = 0.8051529790660225
main.TaskScheduler timer[5]20200714@08:45:58.058: 00> oracle.wh.service.impl.assistant.ProcessEngine.display(ProcessEngine.java:2122): -token name = LOADJAVA; -token type = 13
main.TaskScheduler timer[5]20200714@08:45:58.058: 00> oracle.wh.service.impl.assistant.ProcessEngine.display(ProcessEngine.java:2122): ProcessEngine.token_db_min_ver =
main.TaskScheduler timer[5]20200714@08:45:58.058: 00> oracle.wh.service.impl.assistant.ProcessEngine.display(ProcessEngine.java:2122): Before processing LOADJAVA Token
main.TaskScheduler timer[5]20200714@08:45:58.058: 00> oracle.wh.service.impl.assistant.ProcessEngine.display(ProcessEngine.java:2122): ... I am in processLoadJavaToken ...
main.AWT-EventQueue-0[6]20200714@08:48:36.036: 00> oracle.wh.ui.jcommon.WhButton@424c414: WhButton setLabel rtsString = Yes
main.AWT-EventQueue-0[6]20200714@08:48:36.036: 00> oracle.wh.ui.jcommon.WhButton@424c414: WhButton setLabel rtsString = No
```

The following is the list of database patches.

```
Patch  17906774: applied on Wed Aug 04 11:21:52 BDT 2021
Unique Patch ID:  17692968
   Created on 14 May 2014, 22:56:54 hrs PST8PDT
   Bugs fixed:
     17607032, 17974168, 17669786, 17561509, 16885825, 18274560, 17613052
     17461930, 16829998, 17251918, 17435868, 17279666, 17328020, 17006987
     18260620, 16833468, 18180599, 17292119, 17340242, 17296559, 15990966
     17438322, 17939651, 17359696, 18385759, 17820353, 17939225, 17715818
     18192446, 16960088, 17191248, 17422695

Patch  31668908     : applied on Mon Jul 12 16:13:02 BDT 2021
Unique Patch ID:  23822194
Patch description:  "OJVM PATCH SET UPDATE 11.2.0.4.201020"
   Created on 18 Sep 2020, 03:30:45 hrs PST8PDT
   Bugs fixed:
     23727132, 19554117, 19006757, 14774730, 18933818, 18458318, 18166577
     19231857, 19153980, 19058059, 19007266, 17285560, 17201047, 17056813
     19223010, 19852360, 19909862, 19895326, 19374518, 20408829, 21047766
     21566944, 19176885, 17804361, 17528315, 21811517, 22253904, 19187988
     21911849, 22118835, 22670385, 23265914, 22675136, 24448240, 25067795
     24534298, 25076732, 25494379, 26023002, 19699946, 26637592, 27000663
     25649873, 27461842, 27952577, 27642235, 28502128, 28915933, 29254615
     29774367, 29992392, 29448234, 30160639, 30534664, 30855121, 31306274
     30772207, 31476032, 30561292, 28394726, 26716835, 24817447, 23082876
     31668867

Patch  31537677     : applied on Thu Jul 08 11:53:10 BDT 2021
Unique Patch ID:  23852314
Patch description:  "Database Patch Set Update : 11.2.0.4.201020 (31537677)"
```

Comment: Would you please share the applied patches in your database.

Comment: @Dr.Md.RejaulKarim, I have edit the question with applied patches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the workaround to fix the issue.

Step 1: Rollback the patches 31668908 and 31537677. OWB does not support with OJVM patch newer than December 2018

Step 2:Re-run the repository assistant.